# Replacing a Lithium-Ion battery with an array of lead-acid batteries

Tags: batteries

I have an electrical bicycle that I rarely use, and I'm thinking about turning it into a project.

The electrical bicycle has a 36V Lithium-Ion battery. When it's fully charged, it produces around 42V (36V is measured when it's fully discharged). It's completely okay, but I want to test out something different.

I figured out that for the price of a new 15Ah 36V Lithium-Ion battery I can get 3 12V 41Ah (99RC) lead-acid batteries. If put in series, it'll produce 36V for 41Ah. That's more than twice the energy for the same price!

Except for the lead acid batteries having a slightly lower voltage (36V < 42V) than the Lithium-Ion counterparts, shorted lifetime and disregarding weight and size, what major disadvantages will the lead-acid batteries have?

Comment: Weight and size *are major* disadvantages. How can you disregard them?

Comment: acid spills on crash?  shorted plates and H2 ignition risk?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Because I know these are the reasons they are not used in commercial vehicles. I'm not planning on using this as a daily driver, but as maybe a way to increase power on the motor?

Comment: You want to increase power on the motor by reducing the average voltage? Novel approach.

Comment: A "12V" battery sits about 13-14V fully charged so the max voltage isn't so very different.

Comment: If batteries are NOT "deep discharge" hey will die VERY quickly i f usually deep discharged. Even deep discharge batteries should really not be taken under 60% discharged and only 40% is even better - VERY long life cycles with true DD and 40%. Best is probably LiFePO4 at <= 80% DOD. Cost is high but life cycles >> LiIon so whole of life cost per Watthour is best available .

Comment: The biggest problem that you have not considered is that 12V lead acid battery capacity cannot be directly compared to Lithium chemistry rechargeables. Lead acid capacity is specified at a discharge rate of C/20 and an end voltage of 10V. To get rated capacity, you have to discharge it for 20 hours and terminate at 10V. But if you regularly discharge to 10V, the battery will experience premature capacity loss. So when comparing lead acid to rechargeable lithium cells, you probably need to use half the lead acid capacity. So you should think of your 41 Ah batteries as 20 Ah batteries.

Comment: There is one other problem. Lithium chemistry batteries generally speaking perform better under high discharge rates. Lead acid batteries will have lower capacity when discharged 1C, 2C, 3C rates that might be acceptable for high-drain lithium cells. So in reality, the delivered capacity of your lead acid battery pack may not be that much greater than what you have now.

Comment: Thanks guys. I got my answer. If you'd post it as an answer we could close the post. :)